# How to re-trigger downstream pipelines via upstream pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an upstream and a downstream pipeline. Unfortunately, I cannot easily re-trigger a downstream pipeline run via the upstream pipeline:

**Expected situation:**
[image]

**Actual situation:**
[image]

The upstream pipeline is responsible for creating the build, and then triggers the downstream pipeline for deployment or undeployment activities. Upstream sets a variable called ACTION in order to inform the downstream pipeline which stage is expected to run.

[image]

My goal is, to be able to re-run deployments and undeployments as often as I want.

How can I re-run the downstream pipeline with either the "deploy" or the "undeploy" parameter set, triggered by the upstream pipeline?

Comment: Note: It seems like this works: One stage [deploy] contains two jobs "init" and "trigger". Init has only one step: echo "Hello World". Trigger triggers the downstream pipeline; it also needs to make the "init" job a prerequisite using "needs". This way, the empty "init" job can be re-triggered as often as desired.

Comment: Nope; it does _not_ work. When the "init" job is done, the "trigger" job is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "retry" bridge jobs from the upstream pipeline, unfortunately. This is a [known limitation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/32559) in GitLab.

The only way to work around this is to re-run the downstream pipeline is to manually retry the pipeline/jobs from the downstream pipeline's interface. However, this only covers cases like failure of a downstream job. Retrying can't change the pipeline structure itself (like what jobs are included) because `rules:` are **only** evaluated at pipeline creation time. Even if you change variable settings and retry a pipeline, you won't see any difference due to `rules:`.

My advice would be to not use this `- if: $ACTION` rule. Instead, always include both jobs in the pipeline and set the undeploy job as the [`on_stop` parameter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environmenton_stop) for the deployment job.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#rerun-downstream-pipeline-trigger-jobs) (April 2023) can help:

> ### Rerun downstream pipeline trigger jobs
>
> Previously, if you needed to trigger a rerun of an entire downstream pipeline, you had to rerun the full upstream pipeline.
> This could be a time-consuming and inefficient process, especially if the upstream pipeline has many jobs or other downstream pipelines.
>
> In this release, we’ve added the ability to rerun just the downstream pipeline, without having to re-run the entire parent pipeline, by selecting **Run again** ([image: retry]) on the trigger job.
>
> The newly triggered downstream pipeline replaces the original downstream pipeline in the pipeline graph.
>
> This will save you time and resources when you want just the downstream pipeline to run again.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#recreate-a-downstream-pipeline) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/367547).